# Run PyCharm's spell checking against the whole project

Tags: python, pycharm, spell-checking

I want to check the spelling in all files in my PyCharm project.  Right now, I have to open each file and look for highlighted errors.  Is there a way to run PyCharm's spell check on the whole project?

Comment: It would be hard to run spell check on code, because many things aren't English words and how would you know if a variable name is an error, or meant to be spelled that way (not to mention underscores and other symbols messing things up)

Maybe type individual words you're unsure of into a dictionary (i.e. `arror` above) to see if they are spelled correctly.

Answer (score 11):

You can run inspections against scopes besides the current file.  If the inspection profile has spell checking enabled (it does by default), you will get a view of all errors that it finds.

1. Go to "Code -> Inspect Code..."

   [image]
2. Select the scope and profile, then click ok.  "Whole Project" and "Project Default" should be fine.

   [image]
3. Expand the "Spelling" item in the results.

   [image]

You can also create a profile with only the "Spelling" inspection enabled and run that profile to only see spelling-related messages.